# Pass model from partial view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

So my partial view looks like -

```
@model Example.Models.ForgotPasswordViewModel

@Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 16px; text-align:center; margin-top:10px;">
    @Html.ActionLink("Email Link", "ForgotPassword", "Account")
</div>
```

as part of asp.net's out of the box ForgotPassword view, but I turned it into a partial view. The original view was wrapped in "Html.BeginForm(..", but I obviously can't do that. (It results in a form inside a form)

How do I get it to call the Account controller's ForgotPassword method that expects a model by passing the declared @model?

Html generated by @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" }) :

```
<input class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="" />
```

signature for your AccountController.ForgetPassword(..) :

```
//
// POST: /Account/ForgotPassword
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
        if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
        {
            // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
            return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
        }

        // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
        // Send an email with this link
        string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
        var callbackUrl = Url.Action(
            "ResetPassword", "Account", 
             new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, 
             protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

        await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
        return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Also as Erik pointed out, need to make sure fields are uniquely identified within the partial view. The post had Email twice.

Comment: You can only `POST` to a controller using a form or ajax (IE ActionLink does not submit a form, it just creates a hyperlink).  So your options are to move this partial outside the form, or use javascript/ajax to change the forms destination, and submit the form (but be careful because now you have additional form elements that may conflict with each other on the same form).

Comment: @ErikPhilips How would I use AJAX to change the form's destination?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, it should have read `or use javascript/jquery to change...`.

Comment: Ok.. @ErikPhilips How would I use jQuery to change the form's destination? :)

Comment: You cant use ajax to change the form destination, but you can use ajax to manually post the values of the form to any actionResult or API. This wouldn't be very graceful however.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - thanks for the answer below but, even though I got a break point in the correct ForgotPassword method in the Account controller, the model that gets passed in has one element, email, and this is null. Even though I fill it out. Why would it be passing a model without the entered email address?

Comment: For anyone else reading these comments, as I had stated previously, duckmike has a similar field in the same form that prevented the model binder from binding to the forogot password input (ie there were two input elements named Email).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> @ErikPhilips How would I use jQuery to change the form's destination? :)

I would change the Action link to a button:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 16px; text-align:center; margin-top:10px;">
    <input type="button" 
            value="Email Link" 
            class="change-form-url"
            data-url="@Url.Action("ForgotPassword", "Account")"/>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(funciton()
{
  $('.change-form-url').on('click', function()
  {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    form.prop('action', url);
    form.submit();
  });
});
```

I have not tested this, it should be very close to what you want.

Comment: That jQuery should be pretty straight forward.  Let me know if anything doesn't make sense.

Comment: Even though I got a break point in the correct ForgotPassword method in the Account controller, the model that gets passed in has one element, email, and this is null. Even though I fill it out. Why would it be passing a model without the entered email address?

Comment: Are you sure the Partial is contained within the form?

Comment: Yes, it is there. I have java script to show it on a link click.

Comment: In your question, please post the HTML generated by: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })` and the signature for your `AccountController.ForgetPassword(..)` method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64890/discussion-between-erik-philips-and-duckmike).

Answer (score 0):

BeingForm has some overloads:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName","Controller"))
{
    @Html.TextBox("Name");
    @Html.Password("Password");
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
}
```

Add the action name and controller name into the beginForm call and you can override where the Post is by default.

I suggest you call your partial view outside the main form so you will have two forms on one page (not nested). Then you can point the forgotpassword model to the correct controller method.

Comment: `The original view was wrapped in "Html.BeginForm(..", but I obviously can't do that. (It results in a form inside a form)` exactly what the OP did NOT want to have happen.

Comment: So you've create a FORM within the FORM.  Exactly what he doesn't want to have happen.

Comment: What does override mean?  And I think you meant `point to the correct controller method?`.  What the OP has stated is that he has a view with a form (we'll call it form A) that appears to have absolutely nothing to do with the forget password model.  Within form A, he is calling this partial to display the forget password model.  He cannot simply wrap the partial in a form (form B) because then he has a form within a form.  If he moves form A into the partial he looses the views form and it's function.

Comment: I dont understand why he cant call the forgot password model outside the original form...Two forms on one page. Also I meant overload; made a typo much like yours. Also, an ActionResult is a controller method...Just slang since its the typical return type.